# Perl System() function

Tags: c#, perl

I want to know what would be the equivalent C# code for the perl system() function, see below code

```
$flac = `/usr/bin/which flac`;
($fh, $tmpname) = tempfile("stt_XXXXXX", DIR => "/tmp", UNLINK => 1);

/// Some code for recording

$endian = (unpack("h*", pack("s", 1)) =~ /01/) ? "big" : "little";
$samplerate = 8000;
$format = sln;

if(system($flac, $comp_level, "--totally-silent", "--channels=1", "--endian=$endian", "--sign=signed", "--bps=16", "--force-raw-format", "--sample-rate=$samplerate", "$tmpname.$format") != 0)
{
   if (open($fh, "<", "$tmpname.flac")) 
   {
    $audio = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close($fh);
   }
}
```

Please help me solve my problem, digging on internet won't help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system call in perl most likely calls the command line processor of the operating system with the given string.

In C#, you would use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to start a new process. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has examples to start from.